# Stripping PHP Variables from the URL in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, url-parameters

Here is my URL: http://staging1.mydomain.com/service-list/diagnostic-detail?d_id=2177&c_id=3&m_id=294

As you can see my URL, I am passing some variables through the URL to a page which I have created in WordPress using templates.

We all know that this method is not good for SEO point of view. So I need to strip the variables so that my URL should look like: http://staging1.mydomain.com/service-list/2_variable1/3_variable2.

What is the possible way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you'll need htaccess rewrites. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103230/pretty-url-via-htaccess-using-any-number-of-parameters

Comment: WordPress has functions to create [rewrite rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/), this is also used for the pagination where they turn `?paged=2` into `/page/2`.

Comment: I don't think pretty urls actually factor in much, if at all, into SEO. The readability of the URL though might influence someone sharing the link, which would in turn affect the SEO. In short `/page?id=123` to `page/123` should have no noticeable benefit for ranking.